# Return Values From SQL Stored Procedure to VB.Net Form

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm send parameter to SQL Stored Procedure from VB.Net form. All parameters are pass to procedure successfully (tables update successfully). I want to pass (return) parameter value from stored procedure to VB.net form. But it not return.

When I run SQL Stored procedure manually(in explore), value returned.

Some one please help me to solve this problem

```vb
Call OpenAccConnection(lblUserName.Text, lblPassword.Text)
Dim odcVoucherInsert As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("spPet_VoucherInsert", conAccounts)
odcVoucherInsert.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
' Parameter Assigning
Dim strCompanyCode As OleDbParameter = odcVoucherInsert.Parameters.Add("@ComCod", OleDbType.VarChar, 2)
strCompanyCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Dim strLocationCode As OleDbParameter = odcVoucherInsert.Parameters.Add("@LocCod", OleDbType.VarChar, 2)
strLocationCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Dim strVouDate As OleDbParameter = odcVoucherInsert.Parameters.Add("@PetDat", OleDbType.VarChar, 8)
strVouDate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Dim strPayee As OleDbParameter = odcVoucherInsert.Parameters.Add("@PetPayee", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
strPayee.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Dim strAcNo As OleDbParameter = odcVoucherInsert.Parameters.Add("@PetAcNo", OleDbType.VarChar, 6)
strAcNo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Dim intPetVouNo As OleDbParameter = odcVoucherInsert.Parameters.Add("@PetVouNo", OleDbType.Integer)
intPetVouNo.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
Dim strDetails As OleDbParameter = odcVoucherInsert.Parameters.Add("@PetDetl", OleDbType.VarChar, 150)
strDetails.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Dim decAmount As OleDbParameter = odcVoucherInsert.Parameters.Add("@PetAmount", OleDbType.Decimal)
decAmount.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
' Passing Parameters
' Company Code
strCompanyCode.Value = cboCompanyCode.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(0, 2)
' Location Code
strLocationCode.Value = cboLocationCode.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(0, 2)
' Date
strVouDate.Value = dtPmtDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
' Payee
strPayee.Value = txtPayee.Text
' Account Number {1st Row (RowIndex = 0) of the Data Grid}
If CInt(dgPettyCashEnter("Account", 0).Value.ToString.Length) = 6 Then
    strAcNo.Value = dgPettyCashEnter("Account", 0).Value.ToString
ElseIf CInt(dgPettyCashEnter("Account", 0).Value.ToString.Length) < 6 Then
    strAcNo.Value = dgPettyCashEnter("Account", 0).Value.ToString.PadLeft(6, CChar("0"))
End If
' Details {1st Row (RowIndex = 0) of the Data Grid}
strDetails.Value = dgPettyCashEnter("Description", 0).Value
' Amount {1st Row (RowIndex = 0) of the Data Grid}
decAmount.Value = CDec(dgPettyCashEnter("Amount", 0).Value)
' Accounts Database Open
conAccounts.Open()
' Stored Procedure Process
Dim odrVoucherInsert As OleDbDataReader = odcVoucherInsert.ExecuteReader
If odrVoucherInsert.HasRows Then
    Do While odrVoucherInsert.Read
        MessageBox.Show(CStr(odrVoucherInsert.GetValue(0)))
    Loop
End If
```

SQL Procedure

```sql
spPet_VoucherInsert
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ComCod as nvarchar(2),
@LocCod as nvarchar(2),
@PetDat as nvarchar(8), 
@PetPayee as varchar(50),
@PetAcNo as nvarchar(6),
@PetVouNo as int OUTPUT,
@PetDetl as varchar(150),
@PetAmount as decimal(10,2)
AS
BEGIN

WHILE @PetVouNo = 0 -- 1st Run
    BEGIN -- Retrive Voucher Number
        IF MONTH(CONVERT(date, @PetDat, 111)) = 4 -- Begining of Each & Every Financial Year
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM PettyHeader
                        WHERE HPetComCode = @ComCod AND
                              HPetLocCode = @LocCod AND
                              YEAR(HPetDate) = YEAR(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111))AND
                              MONTH(HPetDate) = '04') = 0 -- No Records Found for April Month
                SELECT @PetVouNo = ISNULL(MAX(HPetVouNo)+1,1)
                       FROM PettyHeader
                            WHERE HPetComCode = @ComCod AND
                                  HPetLocCode = @LocCod AND
                                  YEAR(HPetDate) = YEAR(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111))AND
                                  MONTH(HPetDate) = '04'
                ELSE -- Records Found for April Month
                    GOTO NormalVoucher#Count
        ELSE -- Add 1 to Last Voucher Number
            GOTO NormalVoucher#Count -- Add 1 to Last Voucher Number
        ---- Save on PettyHeader
    END
        GOTO PettyDetail_Save
END
-- Sub Routine Section
NormalVoucher#Count: -- Add 1 to Last Voucher Number
SELECT @PetVouNo = (MAX(HPetVouNo)+1)
   FROM pettyHeader
        WHERE HPetComCode = @ComCod AND
              HPetLocCode = @LocCod AND
              (HPetDate >= CONVERT(date,(CONVERT(varchar,(YEAR(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111)))) + '0401'),111) OR
              HPetDate <= CONVERT(date,(CONVERT(varchar,(CONVERT(int,(YEAR(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111)))+1))) + '0331'),111))
-- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
PettyHeader_Save:
-- Save on PettyHeader
INSERT INTO PettyHeader
            (HPetComCode,
             HPetLocCode,
             HPetDate,
             HPetVouNo,
             HPetPayee)
        VALUES (@ComCod,
                @LocCod,
                CONVERT(DATE, @PetDat, 111),
--                  @intNVouNo,
                @PetVouNo,
                RTRIM(@PetPayee))
-- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
PettyDetail_Save:
-- Save on PettyDetail
INSERT INTO PettyDetail
        (DPetComCode,
         DPetLocCode,
         DPetDate,
         DPetVouNo,
         DPetAcNo,
         DPetDetail,
         DPetAmount)
    VALUES (@ComCod,
            @LocCod,
            CONVERT(DATE, RTRIM(@PetDat), 111),
--              @intNVouNo,
            @PetVouNo,
            RTRIM(@PetAcNo),
            RTRIM(@PetDetl),
            @PetAmount)
-- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
return @PetVouNo
```

Comment: Close the reader then read the value of the parameter @PetVouNo, or add another parameter with direction equal to ReturnValue and read it, again after closing the reader

Comment: Dear Steve, Could you please tell me where I want to put close reader? Before If Statement? or After Do Statement ?

Comment: If you want to read the value of an output parameter you need to close the reader. Of course you close the reader when you don't need its service anymore. So, in your code above, it is after the last end if

Comment: Dear Steve, I done it. Still it shows there are no Rows. That means If odrVoucherInsert.HasRows still failed.

Comment: You should not be calling `ExecuteReader` anyway, because your stored procedure does not appear to return a result set.  Instead, you should just call `ExecuteNonQuery` and then check the value of your return parameter.

Comment: Is this an SQL Server database? If so, can you use the SQL Server provider in System.Data.SQLClient? OLEDB is now used mainly for Access databases. I would be amazed if Access could swallow that stored procedure.